# How to choose two div elements from an array and execute a function on them?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an array `$t` with HTML elements:

[image: Array]

I need to execute a function on elements that have class `row` (2 elements).

Right now, I'm trying to filter elements with `hasClass` method but receive the following mistake:

**hasClass(...).each is not a function**

How can I iterate over the array and get elements with `row` class?
Here is my code:

```
var $t = $(this).siblings('div');
console.log($t);

$t.hasClass("row").each(function(){
   ... 
})
```

**UPDATE**

I've changed a code a bit:

```
 var _t = $(this).siblings('div.row');
    console.log('t ' + _t);
    _t.each(function( index, value ){
        console.log('value ' + value);
        var checkboxes = value.find('input[type="checkbox"]');
        console.log(checkbox);

        checkboxes.trigger( "click" );
    })
```

Now, I'm receiving the following error:

**value.find is not a function**

Comment: Try `var $rowEl = $(this).siblings('div.row');`

Comment: JQuery `hasClass` will return `true` (if the element has that class) and `false` (otherwise), not an array. so it is meaningless to use `.each()` on it.

Comment: I received the same error

Comment: In your updated code instead of using each with arguments, use it without them, and instead of value use $(this)

Comment: dganenco, it works

Answer (score 0):

According to [jquery doc](https://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) hasClass will return only boolean. As mentioned in comments you should use `$('div.row')` selector instead

Comment: In that case, I will select all `div.row` on the page
I need `div.row` in a particular scope